# polymer init (not responding)

Tags: polymer

Im following the instructions on the polymer tutorial:

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/install-3-0

(i have skipped the optional part)

However, after i have executed the command "polymer init" and then selected a specific template, it does nothing more.

```
C:\Development>git --version
git version 2.17.1.windows.2

C:\Development>npm --version
6.1.0

C:\Development>node --version
v10.4.0

C:\Development>npm install -g polymer-cli
C:\Users\nhoyti\AppData\Roaming\npm\polymer -> C:\Users\nhoyti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\bin\polymer.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ polymer-cli@1.7.3
updated 1 package in 8.945s

C:\Development>polymer --version
1.7.3

C:\Development>mkdir my-app

C:\Development>cd my-app

C:\Development\my-app>polymer init
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
? Which starter template would you like to use? polymer-3-starter-kit
info: [init]    Running template polymer-3-starter-kit...
```

What could be the problem on this? I tried checking the folder i have created but still empty.

Tips and lead are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I faced a similar issue `polymer init` went unresponsive after the selection. But, I didn't get that `'uname' is not recognized...` message.

I tried using the following command `polymer init [selection]`. This worked for me. I wanted a `polymer-3-application`, so I used `polymer init polymer-3-application`.

Found that information in [this Github comment](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/1010#issuecomment-390502475).

This seems similar to what @mindon suggested.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day!

Comment: I upvoted, but didn't work again. But @anees-hameed 's suggestion worked well.

Answer (score 3):

It's working in bash.

```
Go to the folder where you want polymer to be initialized.
On the address bar, clear everything and type bash.
It will open up bash prompt.
And then, as usual, type polymer init.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'uname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

^^^ it looks like a problem with the command shell to me.

Try using bash, here's how to get bash in Windows 10:

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#windows-10

Comment: hello Kate! thanks for your reply! However, i have followed the steps on how to install it on windows 10. but im still encountering error on this part "uname" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Can you share the output of the following command: 

`bash --version`

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, the `polymer init` (polymer --version = 1.8.0, nodejs --version = v10.3.0) halted on 
`Running generator polymer-init-polymer-3-element:app...`

same on win7 and MINGW64_NT-6.1

it seems an issue causing by `yield prompt`

here's my temporary solution - edit the source code of polymer-cli to make my choices:

1. find **polymer-cli/lib/init/init.js**

update

`const generatorName = yield util_1.prompt(createSelectPrompt(env));`

with your selection

`createSelectPrompt(env);
const generatorName = 'polymer-init-polymer-3-element:app';`

2. find **polymer-cli/element/element.js**

update

`this.props = (yield this.prompt(prompts));`

with

`this.props = {name: 'my-element', 'description': 'MyElement Demo for Polymer 3.0'};`

Answer (score 1):

Have same problem with `polymer init vaadin-elements-app` on Winndows 8. The work around was to run it from "git bash" shell which is available with git installation (MINGW64).